# Remove a certain variable from a query string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

How do I remove a certain variable from a query string? Say I have a query string

```
$query_string = "first=val1&amp;second=val2&amp;third=val3";

function removevar($var, $query_string) {
    return preg_replace("/(".$var."=[^&]*(&amp;))/i","",$query_string);
}

echo removevar("first",$query_string); // ok
echo removevar("second",$query_string); // ok
echo removevar("third",$query_string); // doesn't change the string because third doesn't have a trailing &amp;
```

How can this be fixed so that it removes variables from a query string in a robust way? Probably someone already has a function that does this along with special cases in more complex strings.

So I'd have to match either `&amp;` or end of the string (`$`) but I don't know how to turn that into regex.

Comment: How about using parse_str and unset?

Comment: why you want to do this, you already have the $_GET array, you can just take the parameters you need and if you really want to remove one, just rebuilt the string using the array without this one...

Comment: To make it more robust, I would ensure that the `$var` is "regex safe" by running it through [preg_quote($var,'/')](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query_string = "first=val1&amp;second=val2&amp;third=val3";

function removevar($var, $query_string) {
    return preg_replace("/(".$var."=[^&]*(&amp;|$))/i","",$query_string);
}

echo removevar("first",$query_string); // ok
echo removevar("second",$query_string); // ok
echo removevar("third",$query_string); // ok
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t necessarily need regular expressions for this as PHP does have functions that can parse and build query strings ([`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str)  and [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) respectively):

```
function removevar($var, $query_string) {
    parse_str($query_string, $args);
    unset($args[$var]);
    return http_build_query($args);
}
```

Note that you need to decode the HTML character references before using these functions.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who suggested the parse_str and http_build_query. Seems like PHP has functions for everything. I will be using that in the future but for reasons I can't go into I needed the regex for this in any case.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have more luck using:

1. [`html_entity_decode`](http:///www.php.net/html_entity_decode) to get the 'normal' query-string.
2. [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str) to get the query string into an array.
3. `unset` the desired key in that array.
4. Use [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query) to rebuild the string.
5. Call `htmlspecialchars` on it to get the `&` back to `&amp;`.

Less concise than the regex route, but a lot less error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$query_string = "first=val1&amp;second=val2&amp;third=val3";
parse_str($query_string, $output);

function removevar($var, $output_array) {
  if (in_array($var, $output_array)) {
    unset($output_array[$var]);
  }

  return http_build_query($output_array, '', '&amp;');
}

echo removevar("first", $output);
echo removevar("third", $output);
?>
```

Normally for codes like this, which involves a query string, it is always best to go for the in-built PHP functions rather than for the regex syntax / formula. That is what I've done, and the main parts of the code include the following PHP in-built functions:-

- [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) Function
- [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) Function
- [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) Function

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removevar($var, $query_string) {
    $query_string = preg_replace("#$var=([^&]+)#is", "", $query_string);
    return trim($query_string, "&amp;");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are functions, that can handle query strings directly.

```
function removevar ($var, $query_string) {
  $array = array();
  parse_str(html_entity_decode($query_string), $array);
  unset($array[$var]);
  return html_entities(http_build_query($array);
}
```